# React native module undefined

Tags: react-native

I  installed  all th libraries  for   stack  bottom  and tab navigation  now   project is not  running   can   somee guide me [[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFOiH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9BXF.jpg)

I want to use  the   stack,  bottom  and  drawer  navigation  in same  project  but  the error  is uncaughtable

Answer (score 0):

When installing new modules, sometimes you need to clear the cache.

- Close metro and uninstall the app on your device
- run in your terminal `cd ios && pod install && cd ..` (If you use ios)
- run in your terminal `cd android && ./Gradlew clean && cd ..`
- run in your terminal `npm start --reset-cache`
- run in your terminal `npm run android`

Other things:

- Make sure you actually installed the correct package by checking package.json
- Check your imports

Comment: i followed the exact same steps you told me to do it did not work for me   still getting the same Error

Comment: ERROR  Error: Requiring unknown module "undefined". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want to run `yarn` or `npm install`., js engine: hermes
 LOG  Running "HRMSystem" with {"rootTag":41}
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "HRMSystem" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Comment: @HaleemaSagheer Can you share your package.json file and the file where you use those packages?

Comment: package.jsonfile==>>{
  "name": "HRMSystem",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.16",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.4.10",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.9.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1", "react-native-screens": "^3.23.0"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1", "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0", "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}